# How to move sessions from a disabled backend server to a live backend server in Haproxy?

Tags: haproxy

A fragment from the rolling update script we use to deploy a new version of our webapp

```
echo "Haproxy:Disabling www1"
hactl disable server servers/www1

# Restart www1
restartServer www1

echo "Haproxy:Enabling www1"
hactl enable server servers/www1

echo "Waiting 3 secs"
sleep 3

# Repeat the above steps for all 3 servers
```

When under heavy load (around 2000 connections per backend server) Haproxy will return HTTP 503 Service is Unavailable for a short period of time (1-30 seconds)

**Is it possible to move all sessions from a disabled backend server to one which is live, without getting HTTP 503?**

hactl

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@" | socat unix-connect:/run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio
```

haproxy.cfg

```
global
log /dev/log    local0
log /dev/log    local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 777 level admin
stats timeout 30s
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon

# Per process limit: The default is 2000, too small for us
maxconn 18000

# Increase the cache from 20000 (default), higher values reduce CPU usage
tune.ssl.cachesize 60000

# Default SSL material locations
ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
crt-base /etc/ssl/private

# Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
# For more information, see ciphers(1SSL).
ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL
ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets

defaults
log global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  http-server-close
option  forwardfor
option  dontlognull

# Set the listen limit: The default is 2000, too small for us
maxconn 9000

# we should fix this
# option accept-invalid-http-response
# option accept-invalid-http-request
no option checkcache

    timeout connect 80000
    timeout client  900000
    timeout server  500000

errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


frontend http-in
bind *:80

default_backend servers

frontend https-in

# add no-tlsv10 for disabling tls 1.0
bind *:443 ssl  crt /etc/ssl/private/site.pem


# Activate compression
compression algo gzip
compression type text/html text/html;charset=UTF-8 text/xml text/plain text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/json text/css

default_backend servers

backend servers

# Rewrite the response location (for redirect cases)
rspirep ^Location:\ http://(.*)  Location:\ https://\1  if  { ssl_fc }

# Every connection is closed and opened to the server
option http-server-close

# Recommended to enable
option http-pretend-keepalive

# The url to check the backend servers health
option httpchk GET /srvstat

# Balancing
balance roundrobin

stick-table type string len 32 size 1M expire 3h
stick on cookie(JSESSIONID) if { hdr_sub(Cookie) JSESSIONID }
stick on url_param(JSESSIONID,;) if { url_sub JSESSIONID }

# We have 3 backend servers, one is for backup
cookie SERVERID indirect nocache

server www1 127.0.0.1:8080 check cookie www1
server www2 127.0.0.1:8081 check cookie www2
server www3 127.0.0.1:8082 check  cookie www3 backup
```